For all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|\lambda| > \| T\|$, we have that $T - \lambda I $ is a linear homeomorphism
The following question is an exercise in a list for a functional analysis class that I am currently taking:

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X)$. Show that for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|\lambda| > \| T\|$, we have that $T - \lambda I \colon X \to X$ is a linear homeomorphism, that is, invertible with continuous inverse.

It has been giving my quite a handful of trouble. Here is my attempt, I am unsure whether the direction that I took is even the correct one, and there are a few steps that I made which feel "wrong":

Since $\|T\| < \lambda$, we have that $\|\frac{T}{\lambda}\| < 1$. Denote $\varphi := \frac{T}{\lambda}$. Notice that
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\|\varphi^n\| \leqslant \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\|\varphi\|^n.$$
Since $\|\varphi\| <1$, the latter series converges, and thus $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \varphi^n$ is absolutely convergent. Because $X$ is a Banach space, $\mathcal{L}(X)$ is as well, so the series is convergent, and we shall write $\psi : =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \varphi^n$.
From the manner which $\psi$ is defined, it is a bounded operator (and thus continuous). Furthermore,
$$(I - \varphi) \psi = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \varphi^n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \varphi^{n+1} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \varphi^n - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \varphi^n = I$$
Similarly, we have that $\psi (I - \varphi) = I$. Thus, $(I - \varphi)$ is invertible with continuous inverse and so is $- (I - \varphi) = \varphi - I = \frac{T}{\lambda} - I$. Finally, we conclude that $\lambda(\frac{T}{\lambda} - I) = T - \lambda I$ is a linear homeomorphism, as desired.

I feel fairly confident that everything until the proof that $ I - \varphi$ is a linear homeomorphism is fine, but I am skeptical of a few parts, specially the final argument.
Any comments are greatly appreciated.

It looks fine. Where exactly are your doubts? You are not sure that after multiplying by $\lambda$ it still remains a linear homeomorphism?

I'd say that that is what has been rubbing me the wrong way the most, I am honestly not too confident that I am allowed to do the things that I did in the last step without causing problems. Is it fine?

If $S$ is invertible, then $\lambda S$ is invertible as well (if $\lambda\ne 0$), because by simple computation $\lambda^{-1} S^{-1}$ is its inverse.

Fair enough, guess I was worrying about pointless things then. Thank you!

A bijective bounded operator between two Banach spaces (completeness is important) always has a bounded inverse. What part of the final argument are you uncomfortable with?
